# How to clear old app's data after app update using React Native (Android)

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, caching, auto-update

Even after the Android application updates the data being shown in the application is still from the old database even though the new data base has the updated data. My application is using Sqlite3 database for React Native. My understanding is that the old database got cached and even though the application auto updated the cache didnot clear, i might be wrong. Please help me fix this issue.

I need help to understand the issue better and apply fixes accordingly

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the old version of the app before installing the new version?

Comment: @CodeJoe yes, in that case, it works fine and the application shows the latest data. But I'm trying to fix this, so that users do not have to delete the application and re-install. I still haven't been able to figure out the cause for this, the issue isn't even common, it is a rare occurance.

Comment: I see. What npm package for database do you use?